# Python rows iteration over dates with a SQL server connection. Iterating over multiple columns in a python data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, date, iteration, rows

I have a data frame with a primary index and two date columns. I am retrieving data from a SQL server with the primary index, the retrieved data has a dollar value and a date.

Initial data frame looks

```
Primary_index   Issue_date    Experience_date
abc101          08/01/2018    08/01/2020
abc102          02/01/2018    02/01/2020
abc103          04/13/2017    04/13/2018
abc104          07/27/2019    07/27/2020
```

the SQL data is this

```
Primary_index   Paid_date     Amount
    abc101      07/01/2017    $50
    abc102      02/13/2018    $100
    abc101      05/23/2019    $500
    abc104      07/02/2020    $175
    abc104      09/02/2017    $175
```

I need to iterate over the Primary_index along with Issue_date and Experience_date, to make sure the Paid_date is in between the Issue_date and Experience_date.

I am iterating over the primary index as shown below

```
df['Primary_Index'] = df['Primary_Index'].astype(str).str.strip()   
Primary_list = df['Primary_Index'].apply(lambda x: "'{}'".format(x)).tolist()   
list_split = [Primary_list [x:x+10000] for x in range(0, len(Primary_list), 10000)]  
filter_list = []
for list in list_split:
    filter_list.append(','.join(list)) 
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
for i in filter_list:
    sql="""
    SELECT
       DB.tbl.Primary_Index,
       DB.tbl.Paid_date
    FROM
       DB.tbl
    WHERE
      DB.tbl.Primary_Index IN ("""+i+""")
      AND
      DB.tbl.Paid_date  BETWEEN  '2017-01-02 00:00:00'  AND  '2020-06-30 00:00:00'
    Group by
      DB.tbl.Primary_Index,
      DB.tbl.Paid_date
    """
    df_final = df_final.append(pd.read_sql(sql,con))
```

The problem with this is I have hard coded the minimum and maximum Paid_date which returns millions of rows.
Is there a way to iterate over the dates in the initial data frame along with the primary_index?

Comment: Hey Sathya, how are you?

Can you give me a little bit more context on the output of this as there are too many ways to do it, I particularly would change the SQL query and search for the ID's as they are present on the first table and them join them using Pandas as it would be crazy fast and if the table grows your mysql will not need to grow too.

Comment: Hello Hugo, the initial data frame has around 3 million rows with unique IDs. the Sql table has around 10M Unique IDs so I am trying to retrieve the information for only 3M rows. Now I understand retrieving all the information from the SQL table and then doing a merge would be faster.

Comment: I am still curious if there is a way to iterate over dates along with the primary index in a SQL query. I tried using param but it does not take a series, param only works with a fixed value.